# Storing JSON in a List

Tags: r, json, loops

I have a series of websites that I want to scrape with the same format (e.g. [www.website1.com](http://www.website1.com), [www.website2.com](http://www.website2.com), [www.website3.com](http://www.website3.com), etc.)

I also have the following code that I am using for webscraping the JSON from each website - I want to use a "timeout" function that forces the loop to skip to the next iteration if a certain amount of time has elapsed (e.g. 1 second):

```
library(R.utils)
library(jsonlite)
    
res <- list()

   part1 = "https://website"

part2 = "extension="

part3 = ".com"


res <- list()

for (i in 1:10) {
  print(i)
  tryCatch({
    res[[i]] <- withTimeout({
      url_i <- paste0(part1, i+1,  part2, i,  part3)
      r_i <- data.frame(fromJSON(url_i))
      res[[i]] <- r_i
      print(i)
      }, timeout=1)
  }, 
  TimeoutException=function(ex) {
    message("Timeout. Skipping.")
    res[[i]] <- NULL
  })
}
```

The loop seems to run - but the results are empty:

```
> res
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5

[[6]]
[1] 6

[[7]]
[1] 7

[[8]]
[1] 8

[[9]]
[1] 9

[[10]]
[1] 10
```

However, the "r_i" objects seem to have run. For example, if I inspect "r_i", its producing a valid result.

I can't seem to understand why "r_i" is working, but storing the results in a list is not working.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout was too low set it higher (maybe `10` is too much). You had two `res[[i]] <-` in your code. It should be just left of `R.utils::withTimeout()`. Also the last thing of `withTimeout` should throw the `"data.frame"`, before it stored just the `i`s from the `print` which should be one line above. Maybe `cat(i, '\r')` is better, it doesn't clutter the console and looks somewhat cool.

```
library(R.utils)
library(jsonlite)

for (i in 1:10) {
  tryCatch({
    res[[i]] <- withTimeout({
      url_i <- paste0(part1, i + 1, part2, i, part3)
      cat(i, '\r')
      data.frame(fromJSON(url_i))
      }, timeout=10)
  }, 
  TimeoutException=function(ex) {
    message("Timeout. Skipping.")
    res[[i]] <- NA
  })
}
```

Not sure which kind of output you exactly want, at least `res` contains something now.

Comment: very clever observation! Thank you!

Comment: I tried to run this code to save everything as a dataframe :  final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, res)

Comment: But I get this error; Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,  : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: I think I have an idea how to fix it... just to clarify, only the last line of code , i.e.   data.frame(fromJSON(url_i)) ... is the code that is actually placed in the "res" loop?

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Yes, it's `data.frame(fromJSON(url_i))`, unless there is a `TimeoutException`, then it should be `NA`.